# Como agregar un delimiter a un text_field en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

¿hay alguna manera de formatear los numeros que coloque en un `text_field`?, me gustaria separar las cifras en grupos de 3.

Hice mi debida investigacion pero no pude lograrlo.

```
= f.text_field(:dr_business_remuneration, maxlength: 28, 
               class: 'form-control only-numbers-money monto', 
               title: t('tooltip.natural_person.dr_business_remuneration'), 
               autocomplete: 'off', disabled:disabled_fields, 
               number_with_delimiter(:dr_business_remuneration))
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
= f.text_field(:dr_business_remuneration, maxlength: 28, 
               class: 'form-control only-numbers-money monto', 
               title: t('tooltip.natural_person.dr_business_remuneration'), 
               autocomplete: 'off', disabled: disabled_fields, 
               value: number_with_delimiter(f.object.dr_business_remuneration))
```

Comment: No funciono bro, seguire intentando

Comment: @ArturoGabriel esa es la forma correcta. En [`text_field`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FFormHelper:text_field), el último parámetro es un hash que se va directamente al input que se genera y `value`, sería el atributo que tiene el valor en el tag html. ¿has verificado que efectivamente haya algún valor en esa variable? Recuerda que `number_with_delimiter ` solo te va a retornar el valor con delimitadores al momento de renderear la página, si pretendes que eso persista mientras un usuario ingresa un valor, debes implementar algo con javascript.